# Will my current Gnome desktop be preserved when upgrading to 11.04

Tags: gnome, unity, interface

I was wondering since Ubuntu 11.04 will include Unity as the default interface, if (when the time comes) I upgrade to 11.04 from 10.10 will my current desktop setup be preserved somewhere, so in case I do not like Unity I can simply switch back to my Gnome desktop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Switching between Unity and your (preserved) GNOME session will be as simple as logging out, choosing "Ubuntu Classic Desktop" at the login screen, and logging in again.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I was hoping something like that would happen. Just to clarify, at the moment my desktop on the login screen is under "Ubuntu Desktop Session", on 11.04 it will be listed under a legacy option or something of that nature? Will it be the exact desktop setup I have now?

Comment: Yes, it will be the exact desktop session, except for any changes that affect the newer version of the gnome2 panel (which are not related to Unity).

Comment: Is it possible (now on netbooks and later in Desktop) to set `Classic Desktop` to default?

Answer (score 0):

Note that session saving is not present in 11.04: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/726431 . I'm not sure if a session you saved in 10.10 before upgrade would be restored, if that's what you mean.